# how to run a remote command with telnetlib3 on python asyncio

Tags: python-asyncio, telnetlib

I'm trying to write a simple telnet client that just runs a single command on a remote box using telnet. This needs to run over asyncio as other tasks are monitored at the same time under that framework.

I got it *almost* working, with the code below, that I tweaked from `telnet-client` as part of the `telnetlib3` library; except that it does not return. I've had a hard time trying to figure what this `protocol.waiter_closed` is all about.

In any case, how do I need to tweak this code so that it returns once the command has been dealt with on the remote end ?

Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging

import asyncio
import telnetlib3

# just to check that connection is thrown away
class MyClient(telnetlib3.TelnetClient):
    def connection_lost(self, *args):
        print("connection lost on client {} - args={}".format(self, args))

@asyncio.coroutine
def register_telnet_command(loop, Client, host, port, command):
    transport, protocol = yield from loop.create_connection(Client, host, port)

    print("{} async connection OK for command {}".format(host, command))

    def send_command():
        EOF = chr(4)
        EOL = '\n'
        # adding newline and end-of-file for this simple example
        command_line = command + EOL + EOF
        protocol.stream.write(protocol.shell.encode(command_line))

    # one shot invokation of the command
    loop.call_soon(send_command)
    # what does this do exactly ?
    yield from protocol.waiter_closed

port = 23
hostname = "fit01"

def main():
    def ClientFactory():
        return MyClient(encoding='utf-8', shell = telnetlib3.TerminalShell)
    # create as many clients as we have hosts

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(
        register_telnet_command(loop, log, ClientFactory,
                                host = hostname, port = port,
                                command = "id"))
    return 0

main()
```

Comment: I figured it out; it is a very bad idea to redefine `connection_lost`; it is this method that is responsible for populating the `waiter_closed` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my mistake, redefining `close_connection` without calling the code from `telnetlib3.connection_lost` is a bad idea, since this is the code that populates `waiter_closed`.

I should have done

```
class MyClient(telnetlib3.TelnetClient):
    def connection_lost(self, *args):
        print("connection lost on client {} - args={}".format(self, args))
        super().connection_lost(*args)
```